# In azure application insight what does Data sampling (0% vs 100%) mean

Tags: azure, appinsights

I have come across lot of articles on data sampling in azure application insights. But not able to understand the actual meaning . As per my current understanding it 0% data sampling indicates azure application insight will not do any sampling and retain all the telemetric data logs to application insight logs.

[image]

[image]
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the opposite from your understanding:

100% sampling means that **all** ingested data will be retained.

0% sampling: No data is retained at all.